# How to hold payment in paygate for a while?

Tags: payment-gateway

I have a query regarding holding the payment in **PAYGATE PAYMENT GATEWAY.**

Here is the problem in brief. I am doing a website where the payment should be made only a certain members buy the product.

For Example if there is an iPhone in my site, then that particular phone must be buy by certain quantities which given by admin. It may be done one by one user or a single user can buy all the quantities at a single time.

In this case i need to hold the payment here.**Because i don't want to receive the payments until the certain quantities bought. Because if certain quantities were not buy i need to refund the money to their account. We don't like to do this process.**

That's why we are looking for holding the payment.

Is it possible or what is the best way to solve this problem?

Please let me know what is you professional opinion?

thanks in advance...

Comment: Has your question been answered or do you need some more information?

Answer (score 1):

You could look into doing a Pre-authorization on the credit card payment and then charge the payment once the quota has been filled.

It's also usually best to ask the payment provider companies those type of questions.

Answer (score 0):

Call your account executive and he will help you with it. Pre Auth is the best way though, agreed